# Metacity/Compiz not staring upon Login Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, metacity

**TLDR:** As of this afternoon, I do not have a window manager when I login to Ubuntu 10.10. I would like to have window manager on login without needing to add to startup.

---

Just started using linux again as my home OS. (Used it for a long time years ago but been on windows up until this past weekend) so this may be kind of n00b-ish :)

Anyways, up until today, everything on my machine was running okay. I did not have compiz running as the default wm because I'm running NVidia Drivers and Xinerama (and as I understand Xinerama & Compiz don't work well together). I made no changes to my xorg / etc but today when I logged in, I had to manually start metacity from command line to get any window manager.

Really not sure what would be causing this or what I can do to get it working again. My xorg.conf is available here: https://gist.github.com/845618. My default Window Manager is set to /usr/bin/metacity in Configuration Editor under /desktop/gnome/applications/window_manager.

p.s. Any tips on how to run 3 monitors where I can move windows between screens without Xinerama would be appreciated but that's prolly for another thread :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1304973&page=2), removing the files gnome-wm.desktop and metacity.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications followed by logout/login fixed the issue. Weird.